# Issues with windows batch file loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the code to loop through a file with a list of servers followed by executing the nslookup command.

**Code**

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=servers.txt
FOR /F %%i IN (%file%) DO (
set server=%%i
nslookup !server!
)
```

**Issues**

1. Even if there is a single line, it loops forever
2. The nslookup command returns no value

Comment: I guess: Your batch file is named `nslookup.bat`?

Comment: @jeb - That is correct

Comment: @jeb - Changed the name and it worked. Why didn't nslookup.bat work? If you answer the post and why nslookup.bat didn't work, i'll accept it.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey when you try to run the nslookup command, you're just calling the batch file itself. You need to rename your script.

Comment: @unclemeat - Thanks unclemeat. Since jeb hasn't answered it, happy to accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your batch file is called `nslookup` - the line `nslookup !server!` is calling the batch script itself with the argument `!server!` (of course this argument is not being used), instead of the *actual* `nslookup` command.

To fix the issue, you need to rename the batch file.